# Running into the generic Error Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct and can't figure out where I am going wrong

Tags: c#, methods, filestream

Here are the 2 methods and the first error is complaining that I need a } where indicated below

I know this usually means I have a missing bracket somewhere but I don't think that is the case and I can't find anything wrong for the life of me.

```
    public Customer(string first, string last)
    {
        FileStream getID = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,         FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        String line;
        string[] fields;
        try
        {
            //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
            StreamReader srID = new StreamReader(getID);

            //Read the first line of text
            line = srID.ReadLine();
            while(line != null)
              {
                 fields = line.Split(DELIM);
                 if (Convert.ToInt32(fields[2]) > CustomerID)
                    {
                        CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(fields[2]);
                    }
                 line = srID.ReadLine();
              }

            //close the file
            srID.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }

        FileStream customerWrite = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        int idCounter;

        try
        {

            //Pass the filepath and filename to the StreamWriter Constructor
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(customerWrite);

            //Write a line of text
            FirstName = first;
            LastName = last;
            CustomerID += 1;
            sw.WriteLine(ToString());

            //Close the file
            sw.Close(); 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // messagebox
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message,"Problem",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            //Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        } // asking for a } here

        public new string ToString()
        {
           return (FirstName + ',' + LastName + ',' + CustomerID);
        }
    }

    // checks for duplicate customer info
    public bool CustomerOrderCheck(string first, string last) // gives the expected class... for the bool here
    // pass the first and last name to be checked in the system for a previous entry
    {
        FileStream customerCheck = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.OpenCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        String line;
        string[] fields;
        bool customerExists = false;
        try
        {
            //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(customerCheck);

            //Read the first line of text
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                fields = recordIn.Split(DELIM);
                FirstName = fields[0];
                LastName = fields[1];
                if (FirstName + LastName == first + last) //(line.Equals(orderCheck))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This order has already been submitted, please try again","Order already exists",MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    //Console.WriteLine("This order has already been submitted, please try again");
                    customerExists = true;
                    break;
                }
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }

            //close the file
            sr.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
        return customerExists;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this:

```
        } // asking for a } here

        public new string ToString()
        {
           return (FirstName + ',' + LastName + ',' + CustomerID);
        }
    }
```

should be:

```
        }// asking for a } here
    }

    public new string ToString()
    {
        return (FirstName + ',' + LastName + ',' + CustomerID);
    }
```

Comment: That seems to be what it is asking for but then that means that is the end of the class but it is not the end of the class, it is just the end of that method.

Comment: Right, the ToString method was inside the method above it.

Answer (score 0):

**You have included a function inside a function. Move the ToString() function outside of Customer() function. 
just give a parenthesis where want and remove the parenthesis after ToString() function.**